# mat-autocomplete options not able to find property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I am try to do autocomplete using [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypmnoj-whmsis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html) code.

Now, the issue is I receiving option as `[object objecct]`, I understood that's because I need to specify the field like `option.name` but when I do getting `does not exist error`. To check I options empty or Not I print it. like below

```
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    if (value && value !== '') {
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
      console.log('this',options)
       return this.options.filter(
        (option) =>
          option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue) ||
          option.clock.toString().startsWith(filterValue)
      );
    } else {
      return [];
    }
```

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSMeQ.png)

**Note:** My code is almost same as above reference, just I am map specific fields from another array.

```
 retrieveAbsence():void{
    this.employeeService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.employee = data;
      console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

```
this.options = this.employee.map(((i) => {
    return {
      id: i.id,
      clock: i.clock,
      payroll:i.payroll,
      name: i.firstName+' '+i.surName
  }}));
```

Output: James Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `{{option['name]}}` also to get the value you will need to `[value]="option['name']"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using value of a dropdown item as and object, but you need a string.
Just change `[value]="option"` to `[value]="option.name"`

```
<mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
          [value]="option"
        >
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
```

to

```
<mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
          [value]="option.name"
>
          {{option.name}}
        </mat-option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the same error getting I tried to add name in [value]

Comment: So now when you updated the example code in stackblitz it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the mat-option, the value should be **option.name** rather than complete object. As you are filtering from an array of object. you should assign the single value not the complete object to value.

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async[value]="option.name">
{{option.name}}
```